# Sound insulation for tile floor: Laticrete or NobleSeal SIS? Do I need backerboard

Tags: bathroom, flooring, sound-proofing, thinset

This will be the first time I do tiling myself. The bathroom subfloor is concrete I believe. I am on a condo top floor so will need some sound insulation.

I am leaning toward [Laticrete 125](http://www.laticrete.com/dealers/products/surface_preparation/anti-fracture/productid/71.aspx), but it looks like it's [hard for DIYer](http://www.johnbridge.com/vbulletin/showthread.php?t=79357). The same thread also leads me to [NobleSeal SIS](http://noblecompany.com/products/nobleseal-sis/). I haven't compared the cost. My questions are:

1/. Could you share your diy experience with working with any of these 2? Is it hard? Cost-wise? I know laticrete is 5 times more expensive than normal mortar.

2/. Have you tried to remove either of these? Was it easy to remove?

3/. Do I need backerboard for Laticrete? Their video and instruction doesn't mention anything about backerboard, just that it can go on backerboard, but can I use it below backerboard as well (i.e. subfloor - Laticrete - backerboard - laticrete - tile)

Thanks,

Comment: Your sub floor is cement so you really don’t need a backer board. I have not used either of these methods for sound proofing but did try an acoustic mat under backer board. Won’t do that again many of the tiles cracked at the edges of the backer.
I pour everything now and it is a little tough mixing and getting everything level but if you can finish cement you should be able to do these.

Comment: Yes, the guy at the store also told me that I don't need backerboard. He only carries Laticrete though and since it's like normal thinset I think I will go with it